# My hyperlink-text appears strangely in my link-bullet-list

Tags: html, css, less

As you can see in the picture:

[image]

When the hyperlink-txt is divided into two lines, then line 2 is not starting below the upper hyperlink-text position.
It does not start from the same place as Line 1.
How can line 2 indented to the right automatically?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left collapse navbar-collapse mega" id="navbar-collapse3">
                <li>
                    <div class="mega-menu">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="/netv&#230;rk">This is a very goog</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/ida-global-business-networks">UPS Global Transtup Transtup</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Her er Css koden:

```
nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li a {
    color: #d9d9d9;
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

a {
    color: #fd7339;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}


nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    padding-right: 5px;
}

*, *:hover, *:active {
    outline: 0 none;
}

*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul ul, ol ul, ul ol, ol ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    background-color: #454545;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 325px;
    left: -166px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    width: 895px;
}



nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    background-color: #454545;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 325px;
    left: -166px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?
I added a new class box just for size of your li element also I styled your symbol for ul, so it looks like
P.S : your code dosen't looks like into the image , your li symbol is the point ●

```css
nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li a {
    color: #d9d9d9;
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

a {
    color: #fd7339;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}


nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu li:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    padding-right: 5px;
}

*, *:hover, *:active {
    outline: 0 none;
}

*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}
ul ul, ol ul, ul ol, ol ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
}

li:before {
  content: "»";
  margin:auto;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    background-color: #454545;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 325px;
    left: -166px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    width: 895px;
}



nav.navbar .navbar-nav.mega .mega-menu {
    background-color: #454545;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 325px;
    left: -166px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left collapse navbar-collapse mega" id="navbar-collapse3">
                    <div class="mega-menu">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 box">
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="/netv&#230;rk">This is a very goog</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/ida-global-business-networks">UPS Global Transtup Transtup</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I dont understand what you have done?. But my bullet is not * because list-style=none;)